How to create scatter shader?
I am trying to make a scatter shader that will scatter an image.
The problem I am facing is that the images are clipping at the border.

I want this kind of result.


I found a similar solution but the image color is black and white and there is border artifacts
Randomly populating procedural shape (or Image Texture) in Cycles


